# AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python

As a beginner in Python, I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here?

I would like to work with `pyautogui`:

```
 >>> import pyautogui
 >>> pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
 >>> pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
 >>> pyautogui.size()
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    pyautogui.size()
 AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'size'
```

Don't know why it doesn't show my resolution? And in general, pyautogui doesn't work with commands like:

```
 >>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, duration=0.25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, duration=0.25)
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'moveTo'
>>>
```

I'm sure I installed pip.

Comment: Have you named a script "pyautogui.py" somewhere?

Comment: Ive made a pyautogui.py in Windows 10  C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pyautogui.py

Comment: You need to rename that to something else. Python thinks that the .py file you saved is the pyautogui module

Comment: == RESTART: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\123.py ==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\123.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Comment: I think the way you've learned what a module etc is, might be wrong. Naming **your** script and then automatically do `import pyautogui` won't work. And having pip installed doesn't actually do anything. Pip is a tool to install packages/libraries, such as `pip install pyautogui` would install it. Then you name your script `maxd.py` and do `import pyautogui`. But having pip installed and then just doing `import X` won't do anything, it's not a "when i run something, and i don't have the lib, pip will fix it for me". It's not like IntelliJ/Gradle in Java, if that's your background.

Answer (score 0):

Your own script which is named "pyautogui.py" is interfering with the module you installed — so rename it something else.